# Insert values statement can contain only constant literal values or variable references error while running below procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I am getting:

> Insert values statement can contain only constant literal values or variable references error

while running the below procedure at insertion in `dbo.DB_time_log` table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_chm_dedupe_import] AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @StartTime  DATETIME;
    DECLARE @EndTime    DATETIME;

    SET @StartTime  = GETDATE();

    PRINT 'Procedure Started at :'
            + RTRIM(CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)));

    BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO [CHM].[UCIC_PAN_INDIA_TEST_TS]
        SELECT
                CAST(UCID AS bigint),CAST(UCIC_OLD AS bigint),CAST(HID AS bigint),
                CAST(HID_OLD AS bigint),CAST(CID AS VARCHAR(20)),CAST(BU AS VARCHAR(10)),
                CAST(TIME_STAMP AS VARCHAR(20))
            FROM [dbo].[CHM_EXT_All_India_DL]
            OPTION (LABEL = 'CHM_AllIndia_EXT_Data_Load');

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN;
            PRINT 'ROLLBACK';
        END
    END CATCH;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT >0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'COMMIT';
        COMMIT TRAN;
    END

    SET @EndTime  = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO dbo.DB_time_log
    VALUES
    (
        'SP_CHM_DEDUPE_IMPORT',
        @StartTime,
        @EndTime,
        GETDATE()
    );

    PRINT 'Procedure Ended at :'
        + RTRIM(CAST(GETDATE() AS nvarchar(30)));

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

END
GO
```

Comment: Table structure is :

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DB_time_log]
(
 ProcedureName VARCHAR(4000),
 StartTime  DATETIME,
 EndTime   DATETIME,
 InsertDate  DATETIME
);

Comment: Are you sure it's failing on the insert into dbo.DB_time_log statement and not some trigger? Also, ProcedureName's column type could be `nvarchar(128)`, or `sysname` which is a synonym.

Comment: Yes,it's failing on the insert into dbo.DB_time_log statement .

Comment: @AkashPatil where did you create and run the stored procedure, in SQL SQL , Azure SQL database or Azrue synapse?

Comment: @LeonYue at Azure synapse